# Insert layer file to MXDs with multiple data frames using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have 4  mxd's and I want to insert layer file to each mxd with position in the TOC. Each mxd has 3 and more data frame. I don't know why it does't work.
I'm trying this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis"   
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis\\" + mxdname)
    refLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "roads", df)[0] # as display in TOC
    insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis\layers\residence.lyr")
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):                                              
            arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, insertLayer, "AFTER") # BEFORE\ AFTER


    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is another code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env



env.workspace = r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis"   
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis\\" + mxdname)
    insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis\layers\17.12.13\range400.lyr")
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.name =="SP-06-ROW.dwg Polyline":
                arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, lyr, insertLayer, "AFTER") 
                print 'InsertLayer'

    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: If I read right, the question was: Why it doesn't work? I guess Hornbydd answers the question. You show the code that works but it is not the answer. IMO.

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
refLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "roads", df)[0]
```

You reference `df` before you ever create it. If you remove it then it should return a list with just the roads layer in it.

Then the logic of the code becomes odd as you then go through ALL the dataframes attempting to insert a layer after roads. Your `reflayer` is coming from the first dataframe...

If every dataframe contains a road layer then it makes more sense to cycle through the dataframes getting a handle on the road layer in that dataframe and then do the insert.

Answer (score 1):

this code solved my problem:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env
import string


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"   
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    insertLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Project\layers\ways.lyr")
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
    ex = 0 
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
        if insertLayer == lyr: 

            ex = 1   
    if ex == 0:     
        refLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "atikot", df)[0] 
        arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, insertLayer, "AFTER")
        print mxdname
        print 'InsertLayer'               
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```